# IOS setting property syntax issue

Tags: objective-c, ios, syntax, properties

Could someone explain to me why this works :

```
SpecialView *view = [[SpecialView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 164)];
self.specialView = view;
self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.specialView;
```

And this doesn't :

```
self.specialView = [[SpecialView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 164)];
self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.specialView;
```

Thank you very much !

EDIT 1 : The property in .h is like :

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) SpecialView *specialView;
```

When I mean it doesn't work, I mean the at the end the self.specialView is nil.
(And yes I'm using ARC)

Comment: Show your property declaration for these two

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? It looks right (assuming ARC).

Comment: Edited to answer both of you :)

Comment: Can you print self.specialView i.e., NSLog(@"%@",self.specialView); in both cases.

Comment: If this is the only place you use specialView, then I think it's unnecessary. Just change the left side of the first line of code you posted to "self.tableView.tableHeaderView". That should be all you need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your property is defined as `weak`. This means the reference isn't retained. It also means that when the object is deallocated, the property will be set to `nil`.

In the first bit of code you assign the `SpecialView` instance to a local (strong) variable. This keeps the object around for a bit. Then you assign the instance to the (weak) property. This doesn't help any. But then you assign the weak property to the table view's header. It's this extra reference that keeps the instance alive after the local variable `view` goes out of scope. But if you were to assign another header to the table or if the table view went away, the special view would be released and deallocated and the property would be reset to nil.

In the second bit of code, you don't have the local variable. So the object gets released and deallocated immediately and the property gets reset to `nil`.

Most likely your property needs to be defined as `strong` instead of `weak`.

Comment: Ok it works, thank you very much, I'll choose you as the right answer but could you just tell me why the tableView is fine with being weak and not this headerView ? THank you

Comment: Probably because the table view was added as a subview so it still has other references to it.

Comment: @rmaddy, won't the first one be ok, since the table view will retain its header view?

Comment: @rdelmar Yes. I overlooked that last assignment. I got focused on the first two lines. I'll update my answer to reflect this detail. Thanks.

Comment: Even though I think too it should work if it isn't strong it doesn't, that's why I made the question in the first place :/

Comment: It will work as weak only if you ensure there are other references to the object at all times like in the first bit of code.